# AngularJs application going to the top of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm creating a single page web app using AngularJs and I am having trouble with showing information as if they were in different panels.

So basically each panel contains text and photos, basic information slides. I am currently showing and hiding these using a left and right arrow.

But when I go from one panel to the next, the next div is scrolled to the bottom  of the div.

On the click of the next arrow, I also need the next div to be at the top no matter what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should add a jsbin/jsfiddle/plunkr, without that no help is possible.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Comment: Sorry, I normally would have I just need to create a simple example. I'll post a URL shorlty.

Answer (score 0):

As @ferTo says, you should provide some code for us to comment on. Assuming you are using ui-router (which I have no idea in practise) then you will want to turn off autoscroll

```
<div ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, will post a URL shortly. Although I did add this to my code . It did make a change and move the scroll upwards but about 70px short of the top.